# Error when trying to bakup from SQL Server 2012 to Azure

Tags: azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to do a backup from SQL Server 2012 to Azure (free account), but I'm getting this error:

'URL' is not a recognized Device Type option

I´m writing the instruction like this:

```
BACKUP DATABASE DB_Verifica
TO URL = N'https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/myContainer/MyDatabase.bak'
WITH CREDENTIAL = 'SQLBackups';
GO
```

The size of the DB is small (less than 2 GB), I'm just trying out the Azure services.

The SQL Server 2012 does not recognize the word URL, I looked up for a solution on the web and I founded I was needing the SP1 Compact 2 or later versions to install, so I installed the mos recently version of SP1 Compact 4 and.. did not work.

Do you have any suggestions to solve my problem?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Can you run `SELECT @@VERSION` and post that up?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I worked by installing the SP4